# How do I show only the open form and not the Access Objects page?

Tags: string

We converted from Access 16 to 365 and now I'm having a myriad of issues.  I don't want the user to see Access objects (tables, forms, etc.).  I only want the current form to show on screen, which I can minimize on the taskbar.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I unclicked the Navigation option, which removed the objects.  Can I resize the navigation screen to match the form size (so it doesn't show).